# How to open the workspace folder from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse has a project open which is inside a workspace folder.

Can I open the folder somehow from within Eclipse like you can in Visual Studio where you simply right click a project and press the "Open Containing Folder"?

Comment: If you try the plugin mentioned in the answer below it adds a context menu called StartExplorer and allows you to open Explorer there, open a cmd prompt and more. It adds the hotkey ctrl+alt+e to open an explorer window where the file / folder is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that offers the functionality that you're seeing (and a little bit more) called, StartExplorer Eclipse Plug-in.

It's available here:
http://basti1302.github.io/startexplorer/

StartExplorer's github repo is here: https://github.com/basti1302/startexplorer

You install it by going to Help -> Install new software -> (add the update site url and install)